# Can I take an image of the person trying to log in after 3 login attempts fail?

Tags: security, webcam, automation

Is there any way to take an image after 3 login attempts fail? After that I want to block all ports and shut down system so the person can't access the system using a bootable device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ts=`date +%s`

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /home/sachin/Desktop/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg

reboot -f 

exit 0
```

I use the above script to take an image of the person and suddenly reboot the system. But I don't know how to execute this script at login time providing 3 login attempts fail, so would appreciate any help with that.